# Meu sistema php está funcionando no Windows mas está dando erro no UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, php

Estou usando auto-load PSR-4.
O erro é o seguinte:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Bll\Professor' not
>   found in /var/www/html/unaprojetos/App/Controllers/Professor.php:12
>   Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/unaprojetos/App/Routes.php(81):
>   App\Controllers\Professor->index() #1 [internal function]:
>   App\Routes->App{closure}(Array, 'professor') #2
>   /var/www/html/unaprojetos/App/Routes.php(83): array_walk(Array,
>   Object(Closure)) #3 /var/www/html/unaprojetos/App/Routes.php(19):
>   App\Routes->run('/professor') #4
>   /var/www/html/unaprojetos/public/index.php(8):
>   App\Routes->__construct() #5 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/unaprojetos/App/Controllers/Professor.php on line 12

Assim está meu código:

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

class Professor extends Cadastrousuario{
    /*
     * O MÉTODO INDEX É PUBLICO, PORTANTO O SISTEMA NÃO FARÁ VERIFICAÇÃO DE LOGIN
     * PARA PERMITIR QUE PESSOAS SEM CADASTRO POSSAM ACESSAR ESSA PAGINA E SE CADASTRAR
     */
    public function index($msg=""){
        $view = new \App\Views\Cadastrousuario\Professor();
        $model = new \App\Models\Bll\Professor();
        $view->render($model->consultar(), $msg, "novo");
    }

    public function consultar($msg=""){
        /*
         * VERIFICA SE HÁ UMA SESSION EM ANDAMENTO, SE NÃO CRIA UMA NOVA
         * EM SEGUIDA VERIFICA SE O USUARIO ESTÁ LOGADO, SE NÃO O REDIRECIONA A PAGINA DE LOGIN
         */
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['logado']) == true){
            $view = new \App\Views\Cadastrousuario\Professor();
            $model = new \App\Models\Bll\Professor();
            $view->render($model->consulta(), $msg, "editar"); 
        }
        else{
            header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Essa classe que você colocou não tem nada com o erro, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249714/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código do arquivo `App/Controllers/Professor.php`

Comment: Atualizado. O erro é o mesmo para as duas classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É um problema de *case sensitivity*. Diferente do Windows, o Ubuntu não vai aceitar caminhos em que a primeira letra é maiúscula como se todas as letras fossem minúsculas e vice-versa. Verifiquei que suas classes estão usando nomes em minúsculo, provavelmente o nome do aquivo PHP deve estar com o início em maiúsculo.

```
public function consultar($msg=""){
    /*
     * VERIFICA SE HÁ UMA SESSION EM ANDAMENTO, SE NÃO CRIA UMA NOVA
     * EM SEGUIDA VERIFICA SE O USUARIO ESTÁ LOGADO, SE NÃO O REDIRECIONA A PAGINA DE LOGIN
     */
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['logado']) == true){
        $view = new \App\Views\Cadastrousuario\Professor();
        $model = new \App\Models\Bll\Professor();
        $view->render($model->consulta(), $msg, "editar"); 
    }
    else{
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/login");
    }
}
```

Verifique as classes utilizadas nesse exemplo.

Comment: Mas conferi aqui e as classes estão com a primeira letra maiúscula assim como a chamada nos objetos.

Comment: Nice!!!! Tinha razão o problema é Case Sensitive, porém o erro estava nas pastas BLL e DAL, que na contrução do objeto estava somente a primeira letra em maiúsculo.